# Google OAuth 2.0 for iOS doesn't return to my app

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, oauth, uri, google-plus

Hope someone can help me here.

I have gone through the example app and read all the documentation on the Google website, but I can't it to come back to my app. I have an URI problem.

This is the code from the sample application and I have copied that and used my own app id and I have also tried it with the URI that google gave me, but it doesn't return to my app from the Google+ application.

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.google.GooglePlusSample</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.google.GooglePlusSample</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

No particular errors come up in the console.

Any help would be appreciated.
PS I know there a few question on SO about this, but they weren't any help to me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set everything up correctly within the [Google APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console)? This should determine both whether your application is associated with the Google API project and set any deep linking parameters. The relevant part is in the following screenshot:

[image: Setting up a client ID for iOS]

The special redirect URI, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, inserted by the Google+ client and passed through the authorization flow, should be redirecting the user back to your application after the authorization flow completes, based on your project settings from the API console.

If this still doesn't help, you should check out the [iOS PhotoHunt sample](https://developers.google.com/+/photohunt/ios), as this shows another project that integrates Google+ Sign-In.

Comment: Thanks - I did all that, I will have another go at it.

Comment: Also, there's a new iOS SDK that just released, the highlights in this release are here: http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/10/ios-sdk-1.4.0.html and there was an update to getting started here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started